# Mapbox.js: set map bounds on an area on both side of the date-line

Tags: javascript, maps, geospatial, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/), the `fitBounds` method doesn't seem to play nicely with points that are on both sides of the Atlantic (where the coords jump from 359 to 0).

How is it possible fit the bounds of Alaska or a flight from HK to SF. It might be possible to code a workaround making use of a center point and a custom zoom-level but it feel like a overengineered workaround around a poor handling of the bounds.

If `firBounds` is no help, is there another method like that would achieve similar results?

Example of fitBounds around Alaska, since Alaska crosses the antimeridian:

```
map.fitBounds([[172.461667,71.365162],[-129.979511,51.214183]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Those cases are always a bit of a pain. What may help is wrapping your bounding box coordinates using:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglat#wrap

Another solution might be to convert the bounds to a center & zoom value using:

https://github.com/mapbox/geo-viewport

```
const {width, height} = map.getCanvas().getBoundingClientRect();
const viewport = geoViewport(
      [minX, minY, maxX, maxY],  // the bounding box (west, south, east north)
      [width, height], // map dimensions in pixel
      0,  // minzoom
      22, // maxzoom
      512 // tilesize for mapbox-gl-js
    );
map.setCenter(viewport.center);
map.setZoom(viewport.zoom)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!
I still haven't manage to get the right results from a bounding box returned by `turf-extent`, or even using static coordinates over the date-line; but I'm definitely closer to a working solution :)

Comment: I haven't been able to implement a working solution with this approach.